# Write array inside of a struct from Cpp to QML

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qml

I need to write an array (from external C code) from Cpp to QML. As it was mentioned that this may be an XY-problem, now I first describe my basic intention. I use an external c-program that is given as it is and that I can't change. This c-program provides the following struct and the function mx_get to get the data from a certain position:

```
typedef struct Tmatrix
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    double *data;
} Tmatrix;

double mx_get(const Tmatrix *matrix, const size_t i, const size_t j)
{
    return *(matrix->data + i * matrix->cols + j);
}
```

I need to use this c-program in my QML app, that is 99% QML and 1% Cpp. The cpp-part is a class to connect the QML to the c-program. I use `qmlRegisterType<MyTerminal>` to use it inside QML.

MyTerminal.h:

```
#include <QObject>

extern "C"
{
    #include "external-c-program.h"
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Tmatrix)

class MyTerminal: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyTerminal();
    Q_INVOKABLE void getAllPartitionQualities();
    /* and other stuff not relevant here... */

private:
    TPanel* Panel; /* this contains the Tmatrix at Panel->Q */
};
```

In the QML part, I want to display the content of Tmatrix->data. Therefore I currently use `Text` inside a `Repeater`:

```
Repeater {
    model: nRows*nColumns
    Text {
        text: myTerminal.quality[indexY][indexX].toFixed(2)
        property int indexX: index - parseInt(index/nColumns)*nColumns
        property int indexY: parseInt(index/nRows)
    }
}
```

I did it element by element, but this now takes about 20 secs as the array size increased to 19*19. (In the following code samples, `Panel->Q` is of type `Tmatrix`.)

MyTerminal.cpp:

```
for (int y=0; y<PARTITION_ROWS; y++)
{
    for (int x=0; x<PARTITION_COLUMNS; x++)
    {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "setQuality",
                                  Q_ARG(QVariant, x),
                                  Q_ARG(QVariant, y),
                                  Q_ARG(QVariant, mx_get(Panel->Q, x, y)));
    }
}
```

QML:

```
MyTerminal {
    id: myTerminal
    property int nRows: 19
    property int nColumns: 19
    property var quality: [[]]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Initialize quality as 2d array with size nRows*nColumns
        var i, j;
        var temp = new Array(nRows);
        for (i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
            temp[i] = new Array(nColumns);
            for (j=0; j<nColumns; j++) {
                temp[i][j] = 0.0;
            }
        }
        quality = temp;
    }

    function setQuality(x, y, q) {
        quality[y][x] = q;
        // Assign to itself to trigger an update of the texts
        quality = quality;
    }
}
```

So I am now trying to set the whole array with one call in cpp:

```
QQmlProperty::write(this, "quality", QVariant::fromValue(Panel->Q->data));
```

Therefore I think I need to add this:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Tmatrix)
```

But I still get the error "static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system".
Probably because the double pointer is inside the struct?

What is the best (most performant) way to send the pointer content to QML?

I also tried again with QMetaObject::invokeMethod passing `Panel->Q` (instead of passing `Panel->Q->data` to QQmlProperty::write), but I didn't find help how to do this correctly neither.

Edit: Or can I declare my array `quality` inside my Cpp-class which inherits QObject and still access it from QML? Maybe that's easier.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is `Panel->Q->data`?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you are trying to achieve with the data inside the QML?

Comment: Certainly, passing elements one by one is a very strange idea. Also you have to expose your struct with simple values, known be Qt meta system.  No size_t, and of course no pointers. Ypu have to pass array either as `QVariantArray` or `QVariantMap`. Deriving the struct from `QObject` is highly  not recommended, although you don't want to use properties and signals for your struct.

Comment: @eyllanesc Panel->Q is of type Tmatrix. Panel->Q->data is the double-pointer. I edited my question.

Comment: @codeling I guess you are right. I edited my question. Basically I just want to display all values of the double-pointer from the struct in my QML app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best (most performant) way to send the pointer content to QML?

You can't send the pointer itself directly. You'll need to pack the data into a [`QVariantList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantList-typedef) or a [`QVariantMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantMap-typedef). (Since you're using doubles, you could also store it as a `QList<qreal>` and pass it to QML).

You *could* make your `TMatrix` object into a `QList<QList<qreal>>` by

```
QList<QList<qreal>> tMatrix = {
    {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
    {4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0},
    {8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0}
};
```

This makes it easier to throw your object around from and to C++/QML.

More info: [Data Type Conversion between QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html)

> Or can I declare my array quality inside my Cpp-class which inherits QObject and still access it from QML? Maybe that's easier.

Yes, that may be more appropriate, as your data is large. But note that, your data *still* needs to be convertible to a QML data type. (Again, I suggest the QVariantMap for your object, since that's eventually how JS handles objects.)

This may come in the form of a member variable of your C++ class, e.g.

```
private:
    QList<QList<qreal>> tMatrix = { /*...*/ };
```

You can then fill this matrix in the constructor with your data values. (And it doesn't necessarily have to be a `QList`, it could be a `double` or another `QList<>`, but that depends on what your `TMatrix` is for, so it's up to you. Just make sure it's a [valid type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html).)

Then have a public slot or invokable method which will be called from QML/JS, e.g.

```
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE qreal getObj(int x, int y);
```

And define it like so

```
qreal MyClass::getObj(int x, int y)
{
    if (y <= 0 || reals.size() <= y)
        return qreal();

    if (x <= 0 || vMaps[y].size() <= x)
        return qreal();

    return tMatrix[y][x];
}
```

This is only the getter, if you want a setter, you could define it likewise, with `void` return type and `qreal` arguments (which allows you to then pass JS objects into it).

Remember to [expose your class to QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) (I believe you've done so already), then you can access `tMatrix` in QML/JS using...

```
MyClass  // depends on how you registered your type
{
    id: myClass
    Component.onCompleted
    {
        var obj = getObj(2, 1)  //  calls the function from your class
                                //  use an id if needed (e.g. myClass.getObj())

        console.debug("Retrieved Object at (2, 1):")
        console.debug(JSON.stringify(obj))            
    }
}
```

More info: [Integrating QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html)

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. As I can't change the struct `Tmatrix` itselft (because I need to use it as it is), I still need to loop through each element to buffer it. But now I only append it to a local `QList<qreal>` instead of invoking a qml method each time. Then I return the complete `QList<qreal>` and it takes 200ms instead of 20s. I didn't get it to run with `QList<QList<qreal>>` nore with `QVector<qreal>` though. But as the array is rectangular (each row has same number of columns), I can use `QList<qreal>` and calculate the x-y-index manually.